# Reading line by line from STDIN without blocking

Tags: php, stdin

Basically, I'm looking to read lines from STDIN, but I don't want to block while waiting for new data.  Almost like using a stream with a timeout.

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

do {
  $line = fgets($stdin);

  // No input right now
  if (empty($line)) {
    // Do something before waiting for more input
  }
} while (1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, use [`stream_set_blocking`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) to disable blocking.  Sets `$line` to `false` when no input is available.

Comment: It's still blocking on windows?

Comment: I know this is old, but here's why it doesn't work on Windows, unfortunately:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34972