# How to implement "Press Q at any time to quit" in PHP

Tags: php

I have a terminal-based php program that basically just runs in a big for loop, does a bunch of stuff and then quits. I would like to be able to interrupt the loop, either pausing or quitting the app. Currently I have to hit ^C to quit the app (or kill it from another terminal screen). Any ideas how I might implement this?

```
Running program... 
[Press Q to quit and <spacebar> to pause at any time]
text
text
text
...
more text scrolling by
```

I get how to quit and how to pause, that's easy enough, but I'm not sure how to monitor for input while doing tons of other functions.

Thanks much!

Comment: [This may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308997/stop-executing-php-for-or-while-loop-in-command-line-with-key-press) help mate... I believe he was perhaps attempting something similar.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684367/php-cli-how-to-read-a-single-character-of-input-from-the-tty-without-waiting-f

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [Reading line by line from STDIN without blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966365/reading-line-by-line-from-stdin-without-blocking)

Thanks to the above commenters who gave me some search parameters to get to the right answer ultimately.

The solution is in stream_set_blocking as illustrated below:

```
<?php
  $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
  stream_set_blocking ( $stdin , 0 );

  for( $x=0; $x <=10; $x++) {
  echo "$x\n";

  $line = fgets($stdin);  //Doesn't wait for input because blocking is turned off!
  if (! empty($line)) {
        die();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Pretty great solution.